# trying to connect to Redis using typescript and nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, redis, backend

I am trying to connect to Redis using typescript and nodejs but I keep getting **
error TS2693: 'RedisStore' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.**

```
    let redisCLient = createClient({legacyMode: true});
redisCLient.connect().catch(console.error);

declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
  }
}


// middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "reddit_apples_should_be_next",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new RedisStore({client: redisCLient}),
  })
);
```

Comment: The error states that you can't use `RedisStore` to instantiate a `new RedisStore`, since it's only a `type`, not a `class` or `interface`. 

If you're using `connect-redis`, you have to declare a variable in this fashion:
`let RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do stuff like this

**Basic Redis setup**

Import statements

```
const express = require('express');
const session = required('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const connectRedis = require('connect-redis');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

connection

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

const redisClient = redis.createClient(
port: 6379,
host: 'localhost'
});
```

configure session middleware

```
app.use(session({
store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient}),
secret: 'mySecret',
saveUninitialized: false,
resave: false,
name:'sessionId',
cookie: {

//secure false for non https request , keep false in production

secure: false,

// if true, prevents client side JS from reading the cookie

httpOnly: true,

//session age in millisec // 30 mins

maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 30
}
}));
```